# Json to CSV conversion with value as headers

Tags: json, shell, csv, jq

I have a below JSON file and need to convert to CSV file with some values as headers and below that values should get populated. Below is the sample json

```
{
  "environments" : [ {
    "dimensions" : [ {
      "metrics" : [ {
        "name" : "count",
        "values" : [ "123" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "response_time",
        "values" : [ "15.7" ]
      }],
      "name" : "abcd"
    }, {
      "metrics" : [ {
        "name" : "count",
        "values" : [ "456" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "response_time",
        "values" : [ "18.7" ]
      }],
      "name" : "xyzz"
    }
```

This is what I have tried already

```
jq -r '.environments[].dimensions[] | .name as $p_name | .metrics[] | .name as $val_name | if $val_name == "response_time" then ($p_name,$val_name, .values[])' input.json
```

Expected out as

```
name,count,response_time
abcd, 123, 15.7
xyzz, 456, 18.7
```

Comment: Your sample JSON is missing closing brackets and braces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to rely on the JSON itself to supply the header names in whatever order the "metrics" arrays present them,
then consider:

```
.environments[].dimensions
| ["name", (.[0] | .metrics[] | .name)],     # first emit the headers
  ( .[] | [.name, (.metrics[].values[0])] )  # ... and then the data rows
| @csv
```

Comment: Awesome. All the codes which you have provided are working like a charm. Thank you so much. One small request, I am getting '"' as well in the output. I tried couple of options but did not work. Is there any way to omit them?

Comment: Those sometimes-superfluous double-quotes are correct, but if you want to delete the ones that are truly superfluous, you would have to manually add the quotation marks where they are actually needed, and then use `join(",")` instead of `@csv`.  If you don't care about correctness so much, you could just replace `@csv` by `join(",")`. Another alternative worth considering would be to use `@tsv`.

Answer (score 1):

Generating the headers is easy, so I'll focus on generating the rest of the CSV.

The following has the advantage of being straightforward and will hopefully be more-or-less self-explanatory, at least with the jq manual at the ready.  A tweak with an eye to efficiency follows.

```
jq -r '
  # name,count,response_time
  .environments[].dimensions[]
  | .name as $p_name
  | .metrics
  | [$p_name]
    + map(select(.name == "count") | .values[0] )
    + map(select(.name == "response_time") | .values[0] )
  | @csv
'
```

### Efficiency

Here's a variant of the above which would be appropriate if the `.metrics` array had a large number of items:

```
jq -r '
  # name,count,response_time
  .environments[].dimensions[]
  | .name as $p_name
  | INDEX(.metrics[]; .name) as $dict
  | [$p_name, $dict["count"].values[0], $dict["response_time"].values[0]]
  | @csv
'
```